# IL & stack implementation in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, il

I wrote a simple program to examine how IL works :

```
void Main()
{

 int a=5;
 int b=6;
 if (a<b) Console.Write("333");
 Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The IL  :

```
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.5    
IL_0001:  stloc.0     
IL_0002:  ldc.i4.6    
IL_0003:  stloc.1     
IL_0004:  ldloc.0     
IL_0005:  ldloc.1     
IL_0006:  bge.s       IL_0012
IL_0008:  ldstr       "333"
IL_000D:  call        System.Console.Write
IL_0012:  call        System.Console.ReadLine
```

*I'm trying to understand the implemented efficiency :*

- at line #1 (IL code) it pushes the value 5 onto the stack ( 4 bytes which is int32)
- at line #2 (IL code) it POPs from the stack into a local variable.

*same goes for the next 2 lines.*

and then , it loads those local variables onto the stack and *THEN* it evaluate `bge.s`.

**Question #1**

Why does he loads the local variables to the stack ? the values *has already been* in the stack. but he poped them in order to put them in a local variables . isn't it a waste ?

I mean  , why the code couldn't be something like :

```
IL_0000:  ldc.i4.5
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.6    
IL_0002:  bge.s       IL_0004
IL_0003:  ldstr       "333"
IL_0004:  call        System.Console.Write
IL_0005:  call        System.Console.ReadLine
```

my sample of code is just 5 lines of code. what about 50,000,000 lines of code ? there will be plenty of extra code emitted by IL

**Question #2**

Looking at the code address :

[image]

- where is the IL_0009 address ? isnt it supposed to be sequential ?

*p.s. Im with Optimize flag on  + release mode*

Comment: Is this debug or optimized compiler ?

Comment: @spender release mode+optimize on

Comment: For question 1, it is compiling your code quite literally, but I think the real question is why isn't the optimizer getting rid of your local variables 'a' and 'b' and just compiling it to `if (5 < 6) ...`  Or for that matter, why isn't it just getting rid of the conditional all together since it's always `true`? Maybe the optimizer just isn't that great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why does he loads the local variables to the stack? The values has already been in the stack. But he poped them in order to put them in a local variables. Isn't it a waste?

A waste of what? You have to remember that IL (usually) isn't executed as it is, it's compiled again by the JIT compiler, which performs most of the optimizations. One of the points of using an “intermediate language” is so that optimizations can be implemented in one place: the JIT compiler and each language (C#, VB.NET, F#, …) doesn't have to implement them all over again. This is explained by Eric Lippert in his article [*Why IL?*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/11/18/why-il.aspx)

> Where is the IL_0009 address? Isn't it supposed to be sequential?

Let's have a look at the specification of the `ldstr` instruction (from [ECMA-335](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf)):

> III.4.16 `ldstr` – load a literal string
>
> Format: 72 <T> […]
>
> The `ldstr` instruction pushes a new string object representing the literal stored in the metadata as string (which is a string literal).

That reference to metadata above and the <T> mean that the byte `72` of the instruction is followed by a metadata token, which points to a table containing strings. How big is such token? From section III.1.9 of the same document:

> Many CIL instructions are followed by a "metadata token". This is a 4-byte value, that specifies a row in a metadata table […]

So, in your case, the byte `72` of the instruction is at the address 0008 and the token (0x70000001 in this case, where the 0x70 byte represents the user strings table) is at addresses 0009 to 000C.

Comment: why did the IL supply extra code to JIT to handle at first place ?

Comment: Because writing code that makes this optimization in the C# compiler is completely useless work. The CIL compiler already does that well, why should the C# compiler try to do the same thing?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, because it is easier to compile it this way, and there is no point in optimising out this "extra code", because JIT will do it later. Most of the .NET languages compiler frontends are pretty straightforward.

Comment: guys  , maybe I don't see the whole picture. but my sample of code is just 5 lines of code. what about 50,000,000 lines of code ? there will be plenty of extra code emitted by IL to the jit.

Comment: @RoyiNamir And why exactly would this “extra code” be any problem? Why do you care about that? What do you think the C# developers should focus on: creating new awesome features like `async`-`await` or making pointless optimizations?

Comment: @svick cause if somene had told **me**  : I wrote a meachanism to calc `a+b` , but in the middle I calc `a+b`  and do `e=>f` and `j=>k` but in the end it will do a+b. - **I** will be telling him : _hey so why did you do e=>f and j=>k from the first place_?

Comment: p.s. sorry to be annoying , but I'd really love to understand it. ( and not by : "why do you care about it" ). :-)

Comment: @RoyiNamir, why are you calling it "extra code"? It is a direct, straightforward translation from the source code. It is an abstract, intermediate representation, and it does not have an operational semantics itself. There are no `e=>f` and `j=>k` operations in reality, they're all abstract. Have you ever seen an LLVM IR emitted directly by Clang frontend? It's full of "extra" code. Same for the GCC - its first level of an intermediate code is extremely verbose and not "efficient" at all. Lower level optimisations would take care of all the cruft.

Comment: @SK-logic Am I that completly misunderstood ? `:-)` _I guess the problem is with me ..._  Ok. you say it is extremely verbose. I agree.  but someone will eventually  have to   analyze this extremely verbose code  - **which could have been less verbose !!!**

Comment: @RoyiNamir, yes, you can optimise it in the frontend - but then you will have to optimise it in a backend too, after all the transformations. Your frontend will be much more complicated, with absolutely no advantage over an unoptimised one. "Stack" representation is great for generating code, but it is not suitable for analysis - SSA is much better, but then it's more complicated to generate such a code straight from the source. I had only one case in my practice when I had to do a kind of register allocation in IL level - a generated pattern matching code was too big for a JIT.

Comment: @RoyiNamir It seems you think that not producing what you call “extra code” would be simpler than producing it. But it's the other way around: to remove the “extra code”, the C# compiler would have to be made more complicated for no benefit.

Comment: It would probably help understand the reasoning if you think of the C# 'compiler' more as a a WYSIWYG for IL.  The IL is what is 'compiled' to machine language, and anyone is certainly free to code in 'native' IL, and in fact there are times where that is the appropriate thing to do, perhaps because profiling shows that certain optimizations 'need' to be made that the JIT compiler wasn't able to perform.  However, by first targeting IL through the WYSISYG (eg, any mix of C#, VB, Managed C, etc), the code is often the most portable, and the most retargetable.

Answer (score 10):

I can answer the second question easily. The instructions are variable-length. For example the `ldstr "333"` consists of the opcode for `ldstr` (at address `8`) followed by the data representing the string (a reference to the string in the user string table).

Similarly with the `call` statements following that - you need the `call` opcode itself plus the information on the functions to call.

The reason the instructions for pushing small values like 4 or 6 onto the stack don't have extra data is because the values are encoded into the opcode itself.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions) for the instructions and encodings.

As to the first question, you may want to look at [this blog entry by Eric Lippert, one of the C# developers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/11/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do.aspx), which states:

> The /optimize flag does not change a huge amount of our emitting and generation logic. We try to always generate straightforward, verifiable code and then rely upon the jitter to do the heavy lifting of optimizations when it generates the real machine code.

Comment: I disabled the optimize flag , still , same result.

Comment: Well, yes, it _would_ give the same result if what Eric said is true, and I have no reason to doubt him given he's one of the main C# bods.

Comment: BTW, your assumption is wrong. `ldstr "333"` actually consists of one byte for the opcode and then 4 bytes of a reference to the user strings table, which actually contains the `333` string.

Comment: Thanks, @svick, I wasn't certain of the representation - I've updated the answer based on your information.

Answer (score 6):

There is no point in reasoning about IL efficiency at this level.

JIT will eliminate the stack altogether, transforming all the stack operations into an intermediate three-address code (and further down into SSA). Since IL is *never* interpreted, stack operations are not supposed to be efficient and optimised.

See the open source Mono implementation for example.

Comment: What do you mean _there is no point in reasoning_ . I want to see and learn how things work. I do believe I have a lot of reasons to learn it if I want to be smarter - so next time i will be able to understand things better.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, I mean that you cannot reason about your code efficiency based on its stack representation. It is still a highly abstract intermediate language, not reflecting the real native code.

Comment: @SK has a point there. IL is never meant to be executed (with the exception micro framework I guess). It's just an intermediate code to produce a native binary. As long as all inefficiencies are eliminated when generating native code, optimizing IL is meaningless (aka wasted effort).

Comment: @SK-logic I get your point , but why to write those commands _from the beginning_ ? **why did the IL supply extra code to JIT to handle from the beginning**? Do you get my point ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, since it's going to be optimised by JIT anyway, what's the point in pre-optimising. There's a downside to doing that, since it makes the IL generation a more complex process but I'm not sure I see much upside.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, think of the stack semantics of the IL as of a simple way to serialise expression trees. Just a high level intermediate representation, in a flattened form. Those expression trees are later deserialised back into tree form, re-compiled into three address form and then all the variable access is unified with the virtual register access and an SSA transform is applied. It is a relatively cheap sequence of transforms, which justifies keeping a dense, easy-to-generate "stack" representation.

Comment: @svick, of course there might be interpreting implementations, but the original design implied compilation only. Therefore there are no rich stack instructions (you won't find any swap instructions and alike), therefore severe limitations on CFG and such.

Comment: Old question, but has interesting implications for .NET being run through a WASM interpreter without JIT (i.e. Blazor). So the statement "IL is never meant to be executed" is no longer true. One has to wonder if there are performance benefits to be gained if one no longer assumes JIT will take care of everything.

Comment: @PeterMoore, in such a case, IL is just a very poor choice of an immediate execution VM, there is not much you can do to make it efficient. At least some degree of precompilation is still required - and there are many options. E.g., you can quickly turn it to a 3-address intermediate code that is faster to interpret (see Lua for an inspiration).

Comment: @SK-logic very interesting. So are you saying that the Mono WASM interpreter is just a fundamentally flawed approach then? Because I'm almost certain it's not JITting anything. And it wouldn't surprise me, because it really is slow as a mule and the AOT situation (which translates IL to C++ and then compiles) improves things but not necessarily to where they need to be.

Comment: @PeterMoore if performance is important, I'd say yes, it's a flawed approach, and an intermediate translation step could have improved performance quite a bit. Sadly, WASM is very limited, you cannot do all the usual VM performance tricks such as direct threaded code, but at least an interpreter of a 3-address VM can perform better than a deliberately un-optimised stack VM such as IL. It was designed for an ease of decompilation and further translation into another representations, not for an immediate execution.

Answer (score 0):

To give a final answer to all this discussion about "extra code".

The C# compiler reads `int a=5;` and translates that to:

```
ldc.i4.5
stloc.0
```

Then it goes to the next line and reads `int b=6;` and that is translated to:

```
ldc.i4.6
stloc.1
```

And then it reads the next line with the if statement and so on.

When compiling from C# to IL it reads line by line and translates that line to IL, not that line when looking at other lines.

To optimize the IL and remove the "extra code" (that you call it) in this stage the C# compiler would have to check all the IL code, build a tree representation of it, remove all unneeded nodes and then write it as IL again. This is not something that the C# compiler should do since this will be done by the JIT compiler when going from IL to machine language.

So the code that you see as extra is not extra code, it is part of the statements that the C# compiler has read from your C# code and will be removed when the JIT compiler compiles the code to a native executable.

This was a high level explanation of how the C# code is translated since I don't think that you have taken any classes in compiler construction or anything like that.
If you want to know more there are books and pages on the internet to read.

Comment: Actually, I don't think the C# compiler is *that* simple. For example, if you have `int a=5;` and then never use `a`, it does not produce any IL code for that statement.

Comment: I made a simplification based on the knowledge I thought the OP would have. The compiler has a symbol table that probably keeps track of if the variable is used or not but not where in the code it is used (where in the code in a C# way, it has to keep track of where in respect to the IL).